# Create database on docker-compose MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I would like to create a MS SQL database using environment variables in docker-compose.yml file
:

```
 version: "3"

services:
  database:
    restart: always
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
    container_name: ms-sql-server-latest
    volumes:
    - ./init-script.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-script.sql
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 14033:1433
```

> My init-script.sql

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS some_name;
   USE some_name;
```

But is does not created the database some_name.

Comment: What does "is not working" mean?

Comment: `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS` is not valid tsql syntax.  You can use this instead: `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases WHERE name='some_name') CREATE DATABASE some_name;`

Comment: ---Edited sorry

Comment: Possibly `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-script.sql` isn't supported by SQL Server - I think it's a Postgres-only feature

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example:
https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/tree/master/linux/preview/examples/mssql-customize

MSSQL docker image doesn't have a directory "docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" as PostgreSQL have.